# Can I use POSIX threads in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, posix

Are these available for iPhone OS?
The Threading Programming Guide mentions these but does not say if they are also relevant on iPhone OS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  pthreads are available on the iPhone.  However, Cocoa provides some nice abstractions for multi-threading applications.

Checkout [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) for the iPhone and their description of [`NSOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation), as a started.

If you really need threading, you can use the [`NSThread`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is basically an OO wrapper around pthreads.  You should read the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html), to understand how threading works in iPhone.

Comment: Maybe you could give some pointers for those which you have found to be good ones?